# Excel: substitute special characters without nesting substitute function or creating function

Tags: excel

I have a problem about name ranges in Excel. Excel won't accept special characters like &, -, + and etc. So, I plan to replace those special characters with an underscore. I have this example
ER/OPD & DIETARY. I was able to replace slash,space and ampersand with underscore using the function `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A92,"&","_")," ","_"),"/","_")`. I tried this formula `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A92,FIND({/,&},A92),"_")," ","_")` but I got error because find function returns integer. Is it possible to find and replace special characters without nesting substitute function or without creating user-defined function? Thank you very much.

Comment: both your examples nest the substitute function, why not continue with the first one as it works... and have you tried search() instead of find() ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I tried it just now and they're kind of the same to FIND. I also noticed I forgot to add double quotes for each special characters inside FIND function. It's working now but only `/` gets replaced with `_`. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not.  You might be able to construct a long and complicated formula using `IF`, `FIND`, `MID` with concatenation; but to what end?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I understand especially if I am going to substitute more special characters. Is there a way to substitute dynamically? Thanks.

Comment: How many named ranges do you have that you need to *automate* **naming** them?  Where are these names coming from?

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Its version is 2016, XOR LX and I only have 1 name range, ashleedawg. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have an Office 365 subscription with your Excel 2016?

Comment: No, I don't have Office 365 subscription because I am primarily using LibreOffice. My Excel 2016 is on free trial. Anyway, thanks everyone.